# PrimeFaces Mobile 5.2 and form-based JAAS login not working together

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2, j-security-check, primefaces-mobile

I have a JSF 2.2 application with PrimeFaces 5.2 and form-based login in combination with a JBoss security realm using Wildfly 8.2 and PostgreSQL.

This is working fine and absolutely as expected. The problem now is using the above setup with PrimeFaces **Mobile**. After having entered username and password and clicking the login button nothing happens as I get redirected to the login view again insted of either a redirect to the original requested page or the error page.

Let's start with my mobile login form:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <pm:content styleClass="content">
        <h:form id="loginForm" method="POST" prependId="false"
                onsubmit="document.getElementById('loginForm').action = 'j_security_check';">
                <p:focus for="j_username"/>
            <pm:field>
            <p:outputLabel value="Benutzername"></p:outputLabel>
           <h:inputText id="j_username" name="j_username" required="true" />
        </pm:field>
        <pm:field>
            <p:outputLabel value="Passwort"></p:outputLabel>
            <p:password id="j_password" name="j_password" redisplay="false" required="true" />
        </pm:field>
        <pm:field>
            <p:commandButton id="login" value="Login" ajax="false" />
        </pm:field>
        </h:form>
    </pm:content>
</ui:define>
```

As mentioned earlier the form definition works with the non-mobile version, for the mobile version I just added tags `pm_content` and `pm:field`.

When inspecting the generated DOM in Chrome I can see that the rendered mobile version of the page has different ids for the form and input elements than the non-mobile version and also the `onsubmit` is missing:

```
<form id="j_idt6:loginForm" name="j_idt6:loginForm" method="post" action="/MyApp/login.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt6:loginForm" value="j_idt6:loginForm">
<span id="j_idt6:j_idt32"></span><script type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.focus('j_idt6:username');});</script><div class="ui-field-contain"><label id="j_idt6:j_idt16" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Benutzername</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="j_idt6:username" type="text" name="j_idt6:username"></div></div><div class="ui-field-contain"><label id="j_idt6:j_idt18" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Passwort</label><div id="j_idt6:password" class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear"><input data-role="none" id="j_idt6:password" name="j_idt6:password" type="password"><a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-input-clear-hidden"></a></div></div><div class="ui-field-contain"><button id="j_idt6:login" name="j_idt6:login" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" onclick="" type="submit">Login</button></div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-5673897088131963149:-3654042330506594383" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Now the generated output from the non-mobile login:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="/MyApp/login.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="document.getElementById('loginForm').action = 'j_security_check';">
<input type="hidden" name="loginForm" value="loginForm">
<span id="j_idt11"></span><script type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.focus('j_username');});</script><input id="j_username" type="text" name="j_username"><input id="j_password" type="password" name="j_password" value=""><input id="login" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="5464337132357101375:3961658655950415709" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

If I get it right there seems to be a problem with prepending the ids in the mobile version.

How can I fix this and implement a POST to `j_security_check` in PrimeFaces Mobile 5.2?

Comment: You should be able to just use a plain HTML form without the need for all those ugly prependId and JS hacks on `<h:form>`. For PrimeFaces look'n'feel of input elements, just borrow the desired style classes.

Comment: Oh well... quite easy and I already had the solution in my question when I wrote "a POST to j_security_check" :) I will implement this when I'm at home, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to tinker a working solution with the hint of @BalusC so that my form now looks like this:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <pm:content styleClass="content">
            <h:form>
                <pm:field>
                    <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username" />
                    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{authenticationBean.username}"
                                 required="true" />
                    <h:message for="username" />
                </pm:field>
                <pm:field>
                    <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{authenticationBean.password}"
                                   required="true" />
                    <h:message for="password" />
                </pm:field>
                <pm:field>
                    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{authenticationBean.login()}" />
                </pm:field>
            </h:form>
        </pm:content>
</ui:define>
```

The login is now programmatic inside the `@ViewScoped` managed bean AuthenticationBean within the login method:

```
public void login() {
        log.info("Login attempt");

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(username, password);
            log.info("Login successful");
            externalContext.redirect(originalURL);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // Handle unknown username/password in request.login().
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```